# ResponsiveSlides com JSON como DataSource

Tags: jquery, json, galeria

Depois de muita busca por uma galeria de imagens bem simples acabei por encontrar o [ResponsiveSlides.js](http://responsiveslides.com/) que não apenas é bastante simples, como também funciona satisfatoriamente em *smartphones* (mesmo que este não reconheça *gestures* para troca de slides - mas isso é outra história).

No entanto, como muitos plugins de galeria/slides, o [ResponsiveSlides](http://responsiveslides.com/) trabalha com a marcação HTML existente e/ou pré-definida e é justamente nisso que eu procuro adaptação ou, de repente, sugestão de alternativa pois, pelo menos inicialmente, as imagens usadas serão hospedadas no [IMGur](http://www.imgur.com) e consumidas através de sua API.

Eu inclusive encontrei [uma issue](https://github.com/viljamis/ResponsiveSlides.js/issues/282) no repositório Github do projeto de alguém com intenção similar à minha que foi além com [uma implementação inicial](http://plugin.dk.web1.symatic.dk/), mas que também não obteve sucesso.,

E essa limitação é ruim em termos de performance pois exige que as imagens que farão parte da galeria sejam previamente carregadas, dificultando ou mesmo impedindo o [Lazy Load](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/lazy-loading-images/) delas.

[Conforme solicitado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16945/responsiveslides-com-json-como-datasource?noredirect=1#comment31775_16945), a parte que importa do código atual:

```
<article id="uCSg1">

    <h3 role="heading"></h3>

    <figure class="cover">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Ik3yGs8.jpg">
    </figure>

    <section class="permalink">

        <div class="separator"></div>

        <p>Posted on Sunday, 9 December with 1 note.</p>
        <p>Reblog This Post.</p>

    </section>

</article>
```

Esse bloco se repete tantas vezes quantos artigos existirem na página. O elemento `<article>` tem como ID o mesmo ID do álbum. Nesse exemplo, o álbum é [esse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McQda.jpg).

A imagem no elemento `<figure>` é a imagem de capa do álbum, definida nas configurações do mesmo pela interface do IMGUr. Como esse álbum em questão não é meu, usei a primeira imagem mesmo.

No JavaScript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $( 'article' ).each( function() {

        buildGallery( $( this ) );
    });
});

function buildGallery( article ) {

    $.ajax({

        url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/album/' + article.attr( 'id' ),
        type: 'get',

        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Client-ID 123456'
        },

        dataType: 'json',

        success: function( response ) {

            if( response.success ) {

                // Monta a galeria/slides
            }
        }
    });
}
```

O *data model* utilizado é o [Album](https://api.imgur.com/models/album) e nesse caso produz como resposta [este JSON](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dc10edf105b60505e616)

> A API o IMGUr requer autenticação com uma chave de acesso a qual foi propositalmente falsificada aqui. No entanto o registro para novas chaves [é gratuito](https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/addclient).

Comment: Bruno: e qual é a sua pergunta? como adaptar para usar imagens do imgur? como importa as imagens do imgur? via iFrame? pode mostrar um exemplo das imagens/html que quer sem o responsiveslides? vai recebêr o URL via json?

Comment: Essa pergunta é uma reformulação mais detalhada e mais direcionada do que eu havia postado no SO inglês. A questão é exatamente aquilo que parece, isto é, adaptar ou estender, talvez, o ResponsiveSlides para que este utilize um data-source externo, em JSON, resultado da API consumida (a qual já tenho em funcionamento) para que as imagens sejam carregadas sob demanda e não todas de uma vez, no *load* da página.

Comment: Bruno, pode colocar o código que já têm? Assim posso testar e responder à sua pergunta com uma solução.

Comment: Apesar de isso ter aumentado exponencialmente a complexidade do *stack*, feito. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Como ninguém se manifestou mais, vou dar minha opinião (não é uma resposta, mas não cabe num comentário), se quiser eu posso apagar.

Pelo que vi do repositório [Github](https://github.com/viljamis/ResponsiveSlides.js), o autor não dá suporte a mais de 1 ano na library (parece que ela foi abandonada) e tem muitos `issues` abertos e `pull requests` não aceitos. Não sei se eu usaria uma galeria como essa (minha opinião, :D).

Achei outra, é bem mais completa (e complexa), tem poucos issues abertos (90% deles já fechados) e com desenvolvimento ativo, mas aceita JSON como `DataSource`, da suporte a `lazyload` e ainda funciona em mobile: https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery. Não sei se te agrada, já que um requisito da escolha é que ela seja simples.

A `Gallery` pelo que eu percebi, ela foi concebida no princípio de plugins, isso é, você não precisa importar todos os arquivos `js`, só importa aquilo que você quer (vide: https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery#requirements).

Tenho outras sugestões:

1. Fazer `fork` da biblioteca e incluir essa funcionalidade. Pelo que vi do `source`, ela é bem simples então é só fazer um `decorator` para preservar o código original e apenas adicionar funcionalidades.
2. Se você usa um framework (MVVM, MVC, MVW...), é só fazer `bind` do seu JSON/Modelo no html (gerando os elementos `<figure>`), e ver uma forma de atualizar o controle da galeria pelo plugin, algo como um `refresh`. Nesse caso você precisaria implementar `lazyload`/reutilização por sua própria conta. Sempre que me vem uma idéia de reciclagem em mente, eu penso no algoritmo do `Adapter` do `ListView` do android (http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296).

Comment: Provavelmente eu já esbarrei nesse plugin. E mais provavelmente ainda eu o tenha descartado por ser tão complexo. Ao pé da letra, em eu conseguindo fazer o plugin, seja ele qual for (já estou até considerando outro que não o ResponsiveSlides), usar imagens que não estejam no HTML -OU- usar outro atributo que não o SRC para que eu pudesse me valer da técnica de *lazy load* citada, já está de bom tamanho. Funcionar em *smartphones*, em múltiplas resoluções e etc. seriam extras.